# How to link Ausweisapp2 with Smartphone app

Tags: ubuntu, ufw, smartphone

I cannot link my *Ausweisapp2* to the app on my smartphone (app for german eIdentity service).

Installed via [`snap`](https://snapcraft.io/ausweisapp2-ce):

```
sudo snap install ausweisapp2-ce
```

In the app, there are no available devices shown.

- The docs say the devices must be in the same "Wifi", but my computer has cable only.
- I have `ufw` enabled, but regarding firewall, the [FAQ](https://www.ausweisapp.bund.de/faq) only talks about Windows and that it should work with default settings or the firewall would ask, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

- The docs are wrong. Devices must be in the same network, Wifi or Cable is both working fine.
- The *AusweisApp2* uses the same default port (24727) as defined in [TR-03124-1](https://www.bsi.bund.de/DE/Themen/Unternehmen-und-Organisationen/Standards-und-Zertifizierung/Technische-Richtlinien/TR-nach-Thema-sortiert/tr03124/TR-03124_node.html). ([see also](https://www.ausweisapp.bund.de/sdk/desktop.html))

  So, for `ufw`:

  ```
  sudo ufw allow 24727
  ```

  or more specific:

  ```
  sudo ufw allow in from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 24727
  ```

  Change `192.168.1.0/24` to your subnet.

Then it works fine.